# How to use promises in javascript ? Basic Promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux

I am using redux. I want to perform a certain network call after updating store.
I wrote promise for this as -

```
let promise=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
updateStore() //separate method which updates the store.
}).then(()=>{    
 //Netowrk call
 //axios code
});
```

I am getting a syntax error here : Declaration or statement expected.

What should be the way of performing this activity?

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you don't mind moving it to an `async` function, you can use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), which will do the Promise magic, but without the additional syntax.    Note that `async/await`  isn't compatible with some older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can but not sure why you would want to use promise here? What are we waiting on?

```js
function updateStore() {
   console.log("updating");
}

let promise=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  console.log('update')
  resolve( updateStore() ) //separate method which updates the store.
}).then(()=>{
  console.log('now network')    
 //Netowrk call
 //axios code
});
```

```html
Using promise
```

Might be better served just to use a function.

```js
function update_store(callback) {
   console.log("update store");
   callback(); /* or setTimeout( callback ); */
}

function now_network() {
   console.log("update network");
}

update_store(now_network);
```

```html
Using callback
```

Comment: network call uses updated store values..thats why we want to wait till store gets updated.

Comment: Most network calls have [built-in promise-type handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), so if the `updateStore()` function can be refactored, it might be as simple as `updateStore().then(...)` rather than handing it synchronously, then wrapping it asynchronously.